# How to print first 20 specific lines from first column of my txt file?

Tags: linux, awk, terminal

File looks like this

```
0 0 0
0 1 0
0 2 0
1 0 0
1 1 0
1 2 0
2 0 0
2 1 0
2 2 0
3 0 0
3 1 0
3 2 0
4 0 0
4 1 0
4 2 0
5 0 0
5 1 0
5 2 0
6 0 0
6 1 0
6 2 0
7 0 0
7 1 0
7 2 0
```

I want to modify

```
awk '$1 ="7" {print 100, $0}' index.txt
```

Just to print the first 20 numbers 7 in the first row from terminal.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just add a counter and exit when the counter reaches 20:

```
awk '$1=="7" {print 100, $0; f++} f==20{exit}' index.txt
```

#### How it works

- `f++` increments `f` by one.
- `f==20{exit}` exits awk when the counter, `f`, reaches 20.